# how to uninstall opam...?

Tags: ocaml, opam

UPDATE:
I've fixed the problem, but I'm still confused.

Or, rather, there wasn't a problem...apparently the fact that the opam--version command still worked didn't prevent me from re-running all the installation commands and getting things to work again.....?

I'm really confused as to why I'm not having more problems than I am. Does the version command still work even if opam is deleted...somehow?? Do I have two distinct copies of opam on my computer, but somehow they aren't interfering? I definitely ran the installation twice....I feel like something should be going wrong.....could someone please explain what's going on?

Below is my initial question:

I've messed up some switch somewhere 
(the error is

`ERROR] No config file found for switch
        with-coq. Switch broken?`

if one of you is genius enough to fix this directly lol)

and am trying to delete everything and start over. Opam won't go away, though. I've tried

```
opam remove --force
```

as per [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html) and

```
opam uninstall
```

as per [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/man/opam-uninstall.html), both from my home directory.
I've also tried forcibly deleting the .opam directory with rm -rf. 
After all this, the command opam --version command still works. How do I get the damn thing to go away?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove the `opam` *binary*, you have to uninstall it the way you installed it, either using your package manager, or, if you installed manually, run `which opam` and then delete the file that prints.

The opam switches in `~/.opam` are data, they are separate from `opam` the command. This is true of all package managers and almost all programs, in general.

Comment: I wonder if it is safe to remove the `~/.opam` directory after writing `opam switch remove <version>`, `sudo apt remove opam` and `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`?

Answer (score 0):

To remove ocaml version including all its packages, use this command ...

```
opam switch remove <version>
```